Vue component reading injected data before async fetch completes
I have a list of customer objects being pulled from an API which I'm trying to provide to my entire app via provide/inject.  Here is the snipped from app.js:
  const customers = ref([])
  provide('customers', customers)

  api.get("customers").then(({ json }) => {
    customers.value = Array.from(json, customer => new Customer(customer))
  })

This works fine for populating templates, but in the condition that the first page visited tries to read this data in it's setup, it comes back empty.
For example the following snippet from a component's setup script:
  const customers = inject('customers')

  const customer = ref(null)
  customer.value = customers.value.filter(customer => customer.id === route.params.customer_id)[0]

The only solution I can think of is to also provide/inject the promises and await them in the components, but this doesn't sound like a very good solution.  Is there another way that I'm missing?

You can either block the whole comp tree by awaiting a promise in app.js, or inject a promise and await it in children. Both need suspense to work. Consider explaining your case in details, a possible solution could depend on this. If you don't need 'customers' anywhere (this is when loose coupling becomes an antipattern) but on some pages, you could move fetch operations to a router. And you may not need provide/inject, it's for special cases that need DI.

@EstusFlask I'm kinda working backwards here.  The customer view originally contained a handful of routes which were children of the customer route. Customer related things are now most of what the app does now.
I'm trying to move customer selection to the sideNav component.  I still need a couple views to have access to manipulate the customers array or read the entire list of customers.
The affected routes are /customer/:id/, which are children of /customer/:id.  When the customer view loads it sets globalCustomer to match the customer whos id is in the route.

If fetch is needed in a limited amount of routes then router hook or view component's async setup (which is roughly the same as beforeRouteEnter) is a reasonable place to fetch it. It makes sense to make 'customers' global store instead of some component state because you won't be able to use inject() in router hook. You can add caching behavior to the store if needed, or use some third-party solution like vue-query. As said, provide/inject allows for DI that isn't commonly needed
